# prove that $f(x)=x+\tan^{-1}(x)$ is a bijection

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x)=x+\tan^{-1}(x)$ show that $f$ is a bijective and find $f$ inverse.

as the function is monotonic and continuous it is injective how will i show surjective ?

But how will I find the inverse, can I apply inverse implicit theorem?

Comment: a monotonic function on an interval is bijective

Comment: Monotone decreasing doesn't imply bijective.

Comment: $e^{-x}$ is bijective not bijection

Comment: Strictly monotonic because $f'(x)>0$, and then compute limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to\pm\infty$ to show the image of $]-\infty,+\infty[$ is $]-\infty,+\infty[$. A strictly monotonic function is indeed a bijection from its domain to its **image**.

Comment: take limit on f(x) or f'(x)

Comment: What are the domain and range of $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ $x\mapsto{x}+\tan^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: You can show that $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, and similarly for $-\infty$. This means the range of $f$ must be unbounded both above and below. The intermediate value theorem implies that the range must be an interval, and the only such interval is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: how to find the inverse?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy closed form expression. Are you required to find one?